# How to use validation in NestJs with HTML rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

NestJS uses validation with validation pipes and

```
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
```

If this fails it throws an exception. This is fine for REST APIs that return JSON.

How would one validate parameters when using HTML rendering and return

```
{ errors: ['First error'] }
```

to an hbs template?

Comment: Do you have a single hbs error template that you want to render on errors or should the error be rendered in the route's hbs template?

Comment: Errors should be rendered in the hbs template (in the form).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `Interceptor` that transforms the validation error into an error response:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    call$: Observable<any>,
  ): Observable<any> {
    return call$.pipe(
        // Here you can map (or rethrow) errors
        catchError(err => ({errors: [err.message]}),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use it by adding `@UseInterceptors(ErrorsInterceptor)` to your controller or its methods.

Answer (score 1):

I've been driving myself half mad trying to find a "Nest like" way to do this while still retaining a degree of customisability, and I think I finally have it. Firstly, we want an error that has a reference to the exisiting `class-validator` errors, so we create a custom error class like so:

```
import { ValidationError } from 'class-validator';

export class ValidationFailedError extends Error {
  validationErrors: ValidationError[];
  target: any;

  constructor(validationErrors) {
    super();
    this.validationErrors = validationErrors;
    this.target = validationErrors[0].target
  }
}
```

(We also have a reference to the class we tried to validate, so we can return our object as appropriate)

Then, in `main.ts`, we can set a custom exception factory like so:

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      exceptionFactory: (validationErrors: ValidationError[] = []) => {
        return new ValidationFailedError(validationErrors);
      },
    }),
  );
```

Next, we create an `ExceptionFilter` to catch our custom error like so:

```
@Catch(ValidationFailedError)
export class ValidationExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  view: string
  objectName: string

  constructor(view: string, objectName: string) {
    this.view = view;
    this.objectName = objectName;
  }

  async catch(exception: ValidationFailedError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();

    response.render(this.view, {
      errors: exception.validationErrors,
      [this.objectName]: exception.target,
      url: request.url,
    });
  }
}
```

We also add an initializer, so we can specify what view to render and what the object's name is, so we can set up our filter on a controller method like so:

```
  @Post(':postID')
  @UseFilters(new ValidationExceptionFilter('blog-posts/edit', 'blogPost'))
  @Redirect('/blog-posts', 301)
  async update(
    @Param('id') postID: string,
    @Body() editBlogPostDto: EditBlogPostDto,
  ) {
    await this.blogPostsService.update(postID, editBlogPostDto);
  }
```

Hope this helps some folks, because I like NestJS, but it does seem like the docuemntation and tutorials are much more set up for JSON APIs than for more traditional full stack CRUD apps.